# The content doesn't show when hitting the back `button` of my browser

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Below is my router.js  and this is the example of url 
    `www.myUrl/slugName` and the page itself show all the content and data I need.
But when I go to `www.myUrl/slugName/cities/1/areas` and hit the 
    back button of my browser, the content of `www.myUrl/slugName` doesn’t show.

Does anyone had the same experience on why the content of my 
    `www.myUrl/slugName` doesn’t show. Is there something wrong on my 
    `router.js`? Also, when I refresh the page the expected content is shown.

```
this.route('landing-page', { path: ':slug' }, function() {
   this.route('cities', function() {
      this.route('show', { path: ':city_id/areas' });
   });
});
```

Below is my `route.js`

```
model(params) {
 return Ember.RSVP.hash({
   shop:      this.store.findRecord('shop', params.slug)
                .catch(() => this.transitionTo('welcome.shops.index')),
   cities: this.store.query('city', {
     filter: { shop: { slug: params.slug } }
   }),
 });
},
```

Comment: Hi @jeff do you any idea?

Comment: unfortunately no. Maybe also show the routes (especially the model() hook). Right now there's too much that could be invovled/could go wrong to find the answer.

Comment: Anything in the console hint to an issue?

Comment: Can you put your controller content too please ?
Are you sure that the console doesn't pop any errors ?